the images are not uploading it is showing as undefined {Error Handling and debugging Multer"}
here the all the enteries are made except the images its showing as undefinedI’m working on an Express.js-based product management system where users can upload product details along with up to four images. I’ve integrated Multer for file uploads and set up the following routes:

/add: To add a product with images.

/list: To list all products.

/remove: To remove a product.

/single: To fetch a single product.Hi everyone,
The images are uploaded using Multer’s diskStorage. Below is my current implementation.


const addProduct = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {
            name,
            description,
            price,
            category,
            subCategory,
            sizes,
            bestseller
        } = req.body;

        const image1 = req.files.image1 && req.files.image1[0];
        const image2 = req.files.image2 && req.files.image2[0];
        const image3 = req.files.image3 && req.files.image3[0];
        const image4 = req.files.image4 && req.files.image4[0];

        console.log(name, description, price, category, subCategory, sizes, bestseller);
        console.log(image1, image2, image3, image4);

        res.json({ success: true, message: "Product added successfully!" });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.json({ success: false, message: "Something went wrong" });
    }
};

const listProducts = async (req, res) => {};
const removeProduct = async (req, res) => {};
const singleProduct = async (req, res) => {};

export { addProduct, listProducts, removeProduct, singleProduct };


///productRoute.js
import express from 'express';
import { listProducts, addProduct, removeProduct, singleProduct } from '../controllers/productController.js';
import upload from '../middleware/multer.js';

const productRouter = express.Router();

productRouter.post('/list', listProducts);
productRouter.post('/add', upload.fields([
    { name: 'image1', maxCount: 1 },
    { name: 'image2', maxCount: 1 },
    { name: 'image3', maxCount: 1 },
    { name: 'image4', maxCount: 1 }
]), addProduct);
productRouter.post('/remove', removeProduct);
productRouter.post('/single', singleProduct);

export default productRouter;
//multer.js
`import multer from 'multer';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.originalname);
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

export default upload;
`
//server.js
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cors from "cors";
import connectDB from "./config/mongodb.js";
import connectCloudinary from "./config/cloudinary.js";
import userRouter from "./routes/userRoute.js";
import productRouter from "./routes/productRoute.js";

dotenv.config();

// Initialize app
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

// Connect to database and Cloudinary
connectDB();
connectCloudinary();

// Middlewares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

// Routes
app.use("/api/users", userRouter);
app.use("/api/products", productRouter);

// Default route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello, World!");
});

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});


